# jQuery detects click on level 1 menu item when clicking level 2 menu items

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I have this html menu. Some menu items have a submenu.

```
<ul class="menu uppercase">
<li class="mitem">Level 1 Menu Item
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="mitem">Level 1 Menu Item
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="smitem">Name of Collection</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
        <li class="smitem">Level 2 Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="mitem">Level 1 Menu Item</li>
<li class="mitem">Level 1 Menu Item</li>
<li class="mitem">Level 1 Menu Item</li>
```

The Jquery Looks like this.

```
$("li.mitem").click(function(){//when menu item is clicked
        $("ul.submenu").slideUp();//hide all sub menus
        $("li.mitem").css('margin-bottom','0px').css('border-left','none');//reset margin bottom and left border
        $(this).css('border-left','1px solid #E0E0E0').css('padding-left','9px');//add border and padding to this menu item
        $(this).children("ul.submenu").slideDown();//show menu items child sub menu
        $(this).children().children("li.smitem:first").css('padding-top','18px');//add padding to first sub menu item
        if($(this).children().length>0){
            $(this).css('margin-bottom','18px');
        }
    });
```

So basically, when you click on a level 1 menu item it displays the submenu for that menu item by sliding it down. when you click on the next level 1 menu item if slides up the current sub menu and slides down the next sub menu.

However.... and the problem is... When you click on a level 2 menu item it slides up the sub menu and then back down again.

I believe this is happening because the sub menu is within the li of the level 1 menu.

How can i stop this? Its an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You would probably want to use [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) So that it doesn't bubble up to the li

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery consider using the jQuery function stopPropagation.

Use it when you bind the event with your level 2 menu items.

```
$('.smitem').bind('click'), function(event) {
    //....does something here....
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

It will prevent the event from bubbling up, i.e. event corresponding to the parent element won't be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I found by adding anchor tags and binding them with click event as below, it works.

Many Thanks...

```
$('li.smitem a').click(function(e){
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```